# usage of the -s character in verbs

Tags: grammar, verbs, singular-subject-and-verb

I would like to know which sentence is grammatically true?

The failure of the student A and B **results** something.

The failure of the student A and B **result** something.

Since we are are talking about failure of the student A and failure of the student B, it feels like **result**.

However it also feels like **results**, because we don't really explicitly saying the failure for student B.

Can you enlighten me?

---

Quick google search of both sentences (till result/results):

```
... result: About 451.000.000 results (0,67 seconds) 
... results: About 374.000.000 results (0,62 seconds)
```

---

`Deepl` and `Google Translate` from German to English:

```
# Deepl
Der Ausfall des Schülers A und B ergibt
The failure of student A and B results in

# Google Translate
Der Ausfall des Schülers A und B ergibt
The failure of student A and B results
```

---

I am confused...

---

Comment: Consider my comment a passing remark: 1) 'studentS A and B' (A + B = 2), NOT 'student A and B'. 2) 'students A and B' NOT 'the students A and B': determination is already expressed with 'A' and 'B', so, the determiner 'the' is not necessary. Another example, in the same line: 'number 1', NOT 'the number 1'.

Comment: @PatrickD  "the number one" is correct English (for the time being, at least): (1980) https://books.google.fr/books?id=z0KtOtNYMEQC&pg=PR1&dq=%22the+number+one%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjN253TsM3tAhVmxYUKHSK4DncQ6AEwC3oECDEQAg#v=onepage&q=%22the%20number%20one%22&f=false , (2011)   https://books.google.fr/books?id=SZN6e6xEOVwC&pg=PA61&dq=%22the+number+one%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjN253TsM3tAhVmxYUKHSK4DncQ6AEwD3oECDcQAg#v=onepage&q=%22the%20number%20one%22&f=false

Comment: @LPH Yes,  'the number one' is correct only when about talking the number itself, i.e. 1 / One: example 'The number 1 / one comes right after the number 0 / zero', but not when talking about something or someone who is 'Number 1', in a list, for example.

Comment: @PatrickD Yes, in that case "the" should not be used in some cases (is number one, called them number one, etc.). It is true too that "the" could be done away with in "the students A and B" but it is just an option. However you do not have that option for "the number one", although I don't see why.

Comment: @LPH 'the" could be done away with in "the students A and B" but it is just an option.' Nope. Not an option, in that context. It's just incorrect. :)

Comment: @PatrickD I can't see that; for instance you do say "for all students" when "student" is _not_ determined (https://www.google.com/search?q=%22for%20all%20students%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en)  but  "for all the students" when "student" is determined (https://www.google.com/search?q=%22for%20all%20the%20students%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en); this makes me think it is optional; do you have access to a reference that shows your point clearly?

Comment: @PatrickD I agree with that; however there are things that do not add up. "The number one" and "the student A" are rigorously similar constructions; in mathematics it wouldn't come to anyone's mind to say "number one" but "student A" is still correct, and I have a quasi certitude it is so from what I can remember hearing and reading. Also, in your first comment you say  that "the" is not needed because "student" is determined by "A" but then link 2 shows only cases where "student" is determined in one way or another and yet, "the" is used.

Comment: @LPH The links you've provided prove my point: Link 1 is about a book for all Ø students (whoever and wherever... they are). Link 2 is about all THE students OF Sherman Indian School, not ALL students... Note: I didn't write 'The link 1', 'The Link 2' but 'Link 1', Link 2' :) Similarly, would you write '# 1' or 'The # 2' ?

Comment: @PatrickD I agree with that except for "number"; however there are things that do not add up. "The number one" and "the student A" are rigorously similar constructions; in mathematics it wouldn't come to anyone's mind to say "number one" but "student A" is still correct, and I have a quasi certitude it is so from what I can remember hearing and reading. Also, in your first comment you say that "the" is not needed because "student" is determined by "A" but then link 2 shows only cases where "student" is determined in one way or another and yet, "the" is used.

Comment: @LPH Your last comment doesn't look clear at all. No offence from my part...

Comment: @PatrickD I'd like to know, what variety of English do you consider a reference in this matter? AmE, BrE or English in general ?

Comment: @LPH English in general... and British English in particular. I don't think those rules are any different in American/Australian/Canadian... English.

Comment: @LPH This is where you started to lose me: '...'student A" is still correct...'. That's exactly what I said. NOT 'THE student A'...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117263/discussion-between-lph-and-patrick-d).

Comment: @PatrickD Maybe you don't know about the discussion rooms?

Comment: @PatrickD This shows that quite possibly there is no option, as you say: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+student+%231%2Cstudent+%231&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cstudent%20%23%201%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cstudent%20%23%201%3B%2Cc0 , https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+student+%232%2Cstudent+%232&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cstudent%20%23%202%3B%2Cc0 So, I will remove the article from my answer.

Comment: @PatrickD Yet notice how this is not so for instance for "number pi": https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+number+pi%2Cnumber+pi&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20number%20pi%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnumber%20pi%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cthe%20number%20pi%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnumber%20pi%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @ LPH http://masteringarticles.com/nouns-followed-number-letter/ This is my last comment (no offence, again :), as I think you should concentrate your efforts on the notion of determination. Rules will help, of course, but understanding what is at the core of that notion – understanding the crucial difference between something general and something specific, for instance, understanding the even more crucial notion of 'point of view' (the way we consider things, people, situations, when we speak or write) – will help you even more and, eventually, you won't need to resort to the 'sacred' rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the sense of "result" there must be a preposition used with it (results *in* sth). Since there are two students the plural of "student" must be used. As for the person of the verb it is your choice. According to the context you might consider that the failure is collective.

- The failure of students A and B results in something.

Alternatively, you may consider the individual failures, but then a plural should be used for "failure".

- The failures of  students A and B result in something.